# Where is Windows 32-bit installer for OpenShift CLI?

Tags: jakarta-ee, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I'm trying to find an OpenShift CLI installer for Windows 32-bit. The only 32-bit installer I see is Linux. Please help! I am trying to deploy .war file onto an OpenShift server, but not able to because I can't find a 32-bit installer. Thank you!

I was looking in the git repo, and on the site

[Git Repository](https://github.com/openshift/origin)

[Openshift Site](https://www.openshift.com/)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Win32 installer, as far as I found out.

A link where the problem for 32-Bit build is discussed:
https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/18653

The message for the commit:
https://github.com/openshift/origin/commit/c44775a82e27c46f7fa152a16ca775ad75bc07e7

The path to the branch for win32 (if I followed the correct links):
https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/c44775a82e27c46f7fa152a16ca775ad75bc07e7

You'll need to build it yourself, that is the only point.

Comment: Yeah sure I found an issue on the git repo, there seems to be a solution to build it yourself. Read the comments and follow the links maybe binary is somewhere in another branch.

Comment: Okay, can you link it? Thanks!

Comment: How to compile? I tried but it's not working. Don't know if you know any alternate ways.

Comment: I have no clue. From there on you may read the proper information. Take a look at the different md files and so on.